# Solve for X. Where x belongs to R and a>1

Tags: equation-solving

FullSimplify[(Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[a^2] - 1)^x + (Sqrt[a] - Sqrt[a^2] - 1)^
x = 2], a>1, solve for x belongs to R

Answer (score 5):

Get solutions for all odd integer x with investigation of real and complex parts of expr. (x == 0 is a general solution, as @Nasser showed)

```
expr = (Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[a^2] - 1)^x + (Sqrt[a] - Sqrt[a^2] - 1)^x == 2;

fexpr = Subtract @@ expr

ceRe = ComplexExpand[Re[fexpr], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, a > 1 && x \[Element] Reals] &

(*   -2 + (-1 + Sqrt[a] + a)^x + (1 - Sqrt[a] + a)^x Cos[\[Pi] x]   *)

ceIm = ComplexExpand[Im[fexpr], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, a > 1 && x \[Element] Reals] &

(*   (1 - Sqrt[a] + a)^x Sin[\[Pi] x]   *)
```

Imaginary part allows all integer as solutions for x, but real part restricts it to odd integers greater zero.

```
solIm[c1_] = 
 Flatten@Solve[ceIm == 0 && a > 1, x, Reals] /. C[1] -> c1 // 
  Simplify[#, a > 1] &

(*   {x -> ConditionalExpression[2 c1, c1 \[Element] Integers], 
 x -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 2 c1, c1 \[Element] Integers]}   *)

(tab = Table[{x -> c1, 
     First@First@
       Solve[(ceRe /. x -> c1) == 0 && a > 1, a, Reals]}, {c1, -5, 
     15}]) // TableForm

solutions = Rest@DeleteCases[tab, {_, {}}]

(*   {{x -> 1, a -> 4}, {x -> 3, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 3 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 - 3 #1^4 + 3 #1^5 &, 
    1]^2}, {x -> 5, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 5 #1 - 10 #1^2 + 10 #1^3 - 15 #1^4 + 31 #1^5 - 
      30 #1^6 + 10 #1^7 - 5 #1^8 + 5 #1^9 &, 1]^2}, {x -> 7, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 7 #1 - 21 #1^2 + 35 #1^3 - 56 #1^4 + 126 #1^5 - 
      217 #1^6 + 211 #1^7 - 140 #1^8 + 126 #1^9 - 105 #1^10 + 
      35 #1^11 - 7 #1^12 + 7 #1^13 &, 1]^2}, {x -> 9, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 9 #1 - 36 #1^2 + 84 #1^3 - 162 #1^4 + 378 #1^5 - 
      840 #1^6 + 1296 #1^7 - 1395 #1^8 + 1387 #1^9 - 1512 #1^10 + 
      1296 #1^11 - 714 #1^12 + 378 #1^13 - 252 #1^14 + 84 #1^15 - 
      9 #1^16 + 9 #1^17 &, 1]^2}, {x -> 11, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 11 #1 - 55 #1^2 + 165 #1^3 - 385 #1^4 + 957 #1^5 - 
      2442 #1^6 + 4950 #1^7 - 7425 #1^8 + 9295 #1^9 - 11561 #1^10 + 
      13531 #1^11 - 12507 #1^12 + 9295 #1^13 - 6930 #1^14 + 
      4950 #1^15 - 2475 #1^16 + 957 #1^17 - 495 #1^18 + 165 #1^19 - 
      11 #1^20 + 11 #1^21 &, 1]^2}, {x -> 13, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 13 #1 - 78 #1^2 + 286 #1^3 - 793 #1^4 + 2145 #1^5 - 
      6006 #1^6 + 14586 #1^7 - 27742 #1^8 + 43186 #1^9 - 
      62062 #1^10 + 85878 #1^11 - 104689 #1^12 + 106393 #1^13 - 
      96954 #1^14 + 85878 #1^15 - 67782 #1^16 + 43186 #1^17 - 
      24882 #1^18 + 14586 #1^19 - 6721 #1^20 + 2145 #1^21 - 
      858 #1^22 + 286 #1^23 - 13 #1^24 + 13 #1^25 &, 1]^2}, {x -> 15, 
  a -> Root[-2 + 15 #1 - 105 #1^2 + 455 #1^3 - 1470 #1^4 + 
      4368 #1^5 - 13195 #1^6 + 36465 #1^7 - 82875 #1^8 + 
      155155 #1^9 - 258258 #1^10 + 406770 #1^11 - 591045 #1^12 + 
      750855 #1^13 - 840855 #1^14 + 879061 #1^15 - 863655 #1^16 + 
      750855 #1^17 - 570570 #1^18 + 406770 #1^19 - 273273 #1^20 + 
      155155 #1^21 - 75075 #1^22 + 36465 #1^23 - 15470 #1^24 + 
      4368 #1^25 - 1365 #1^26 + 455 #1^27 - 15 #1^28 + 15 #1^29 &, 
    1]^2}}   *)

solutions // N

(*   {{x -> 1., a -> 4.}, {x -> 3., a -> 1.37907}, {x -> 5., 
  a -> 1.19974}, {x -> 7., a -> 1.13544}, {x -> 9., 
  a -> 1.10243}, {x -> 11., a -> 1.08235}, {x -> 13., 
  a -> 1.06885}, {x -> 15., a -> 1.05915}}   *)

expr /. solutions // FullSimplify

(*   {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}   *)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it should be `==` and not `=`. But Mathematica can't solve it, even for complex `x`

```
expr = (Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[a^2] - 1)^x + (Sqrt[a] - Sqrt[a^2] - 1)^x == 2;
Assuming[a > 1, Simplify[expr]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Reduce[%, x]

Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
```

But one can see that only `x=0` is solution. (for any `a`)

```
(-1 + Sqrt[a] - a)^x + (-1 + Sqrt[a] + a)^x /. a -> 99 /. x -> 0
(*2*)

(-1 + Sqrt[a] - a)^x + (-1 + Sqrt[a] + a)^x /. a -> -209282 /. x -> 0
(*2)
```

etc...

All other `x` values do not work. They generate complex numbers if `x` is not integer and values not `2` for integer `x`.

So `x=0` seems to be the only solution.

I tried

```
Solve[expr && a > 1, {x, a}]
```

But it was taking too long time, so I stopped it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time in your busy schedule.